# how to block social medias from windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to block social medias from my PC according to time.
Block after 9 PM and unblock after 11 AM (like parental control)
I have tried following but failed.

Created a `block.bat` file

```
@echo off
(Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "#127.0.0.1 facebook.com", "127.0.0.1 facebook.com" } | Set-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Created a `Unblock.bat` file

```
@echo off
(Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "127.0.0.1 facebook.com", "#127.0.0.1 facebook.com" } | Set-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And Added these 2 bat file to Task Scheduler. Block will run at 11 AM and unlock at 9 PM.

I am getting this error from PowerShell:

```
Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the
information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  Path
At line:1 char:140
+ ... e "#127.0.0.1 facebook.com", "127.0.0.1 facebook.com" } | Set-Content
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (# Copyright (c)...Microsoft Corp.:String) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectMissingMandatory,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

And manually running bat file does nothing.

Comment: Hi, what does not work ? The bat files ? The scheduled task ? Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: Please describe in a little bit more detail what exactly it means that you failed

Comment: Running a test script in powershell works file `(Get-Content test.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "from", "to" } | Set-Content test.txt` This code works perfectly. but when i change the path and runs from bat it is not working.

Comment: PowerShell and batch do not use the same syntax. PowerShell scripts have the extension .ps1, and you may need to change the execution policy to make them work. Also, running a batch file shouldn't be giving you PowerShell errors in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Can you suggest me a way to do it?.

Comment: How about you start by investigatíng why a batch file is throwing PowerShell errors? That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Right now I am changing from bat to ps1, and trying to execute it,

Comment: Then your question needs major updating so its clear what your asking.

Comment: @AustinFrench I am trying to block unblock sites as per given time and i would like to do it through shell or batch  scripting with taskScheduler in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a shot for this code :

``````````bat
@Echo off
cls & color 0A & echo.
Mode con cols=55 lines=5
Set Copyright=Hackoo 2016
Title Block-UnBlock Facebook by %Copyright%
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
CLS
Echo.
Echo.
ECHO         **************************************
ECHO                  Running Admin shell
ECHO         **************************************
::pause
:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
Echo.
ECHO.
ECHO         **************************************
ECHO          Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO         **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
ECHO args = "ELEV "
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " " 
ECHO Next 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 
)> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' shift /1
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d "%~dp0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set Copyright=Hackoo 2016
Title Block-UnBlock Facebook by %Copyright%
Rem If you didn't want to create a shortcut and see the intro on your desktop just comment this line below
If Not Exist %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Block-UnBlock_Facebook.lnk Goto:Intro
::***********************************************************************************************
:CheckPassword
Mode con cols=55 lines=3
cls & color 0A & echo.
set MyPassword=Hackoo
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter your password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if %MyPassword%==%password% (Goto:Good) else (Goto:Bad)
exit/b
::***********************************************************************************************
:Good
Cls & Color 0A
echo(
echo                     Good Password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Goto:menuLOOP
::***********************************************************************************************
:Bad
Cls & Color 0C
echo(
echo                      Bad password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Goto:CheckPassword
::***********************************************************************************************
:menuLOOP
Mode con cols=85 lines=8
Cls & color 0B
Title Block and UnBlock Facebook by %Copyright%
echo(
echo(         ================================Menu================================
echo(
for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do echo                               %%A  %%B
echo(
echo(         ====================================================================
set choice=
echo( & set /p choice=Make a choice or hit ENTER to quit: || GOTO :EOF
echo( & call :menu_[%choice%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[1] Blocking Facebook
Mode con cols=85 lines=8
cls & color 0C
Call:SkipLine 3
Call:Tab 6
echo %x% "Deactivate write protection" ...
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Set BackupHosts=%AppData%\hosts.hackoo
If Not Exist %BackupHosts% Attrib -R %hostspath% && Type %hostspath% > %BackupHosts%
cls
Attrib -R %hostspath%
(
echo ###########################
echo # Block Facebook %Copyright%#
echo ###########################
echo 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 ok.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.ok.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 a.ok.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.a.ok.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 facebook.com.au
echo 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com.au
echo 127.0.0.1 nl-nl.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.nl-nl.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 facebook.nl
echo 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.nl
echo 127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com.au
echo 127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com.au
echo 127.0.0.1 www-10-01-snc2.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www-11-01-snc2.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www-10-03-ash1.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www-12-08-ash1.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www-13-08-ash1.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
echo 127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.fbcdn.net
echo 127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com.nl
echo 127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com.nl
echo 127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net
echo 127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.net
echo 127.0.0.1 fbcdn.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.com
echo 127.0.0.1 ads.ak.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.ads.ak.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.connect.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
echo 127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
) > %hostspath%
cls
Call:SkipLine 3
Call:Tab 5
echo %x% "Facebook is Blocked by %Copyright%"
ATTRIB +R %hostspath%
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Start www.facebook.com
::GOTO :menuLOOP
Exit
::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[2] UnBlocking Facebook
cls & color 0A
Title UnBlocking Facebook ....
Call:SkipLine 3
Call:Tab 5
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Set BackupHosts=%AppData%\hosts.hackoo
If Exist %BackupHosts% Attrib -R %hostspath% && Type %BackupHosts% > %hostspath%
ATTRIB +R %hostspath%
echo %x% "Facebook is UnBlocked by %Copyright%"
TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
Start www.facebook.com
Exit
::GOTO :menuLOOP
::******************************************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>%~2
::********************************************************************************************
:SkipLine
    For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Echo(
    Goto:Eof
::********************************************************************************************
:Tab
set "x="
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Set "x=!x!    "
REM                                  ^-- this is a TAB
goto :eof
::********************************************************************************************
:Intro
Color 0A & Mode con cols=101 lines=57
echo(
echo                                      `   ``  `    `   ` ``   ``                                    
echo                                   ```    `  `````````        ` `                                 
echo                                 `    .-/+osyhhhhhhhhhhhhyyso+:-`   `  `                            
echo                                ````/hddddddddddddddddddddddddddhy- `` `                            
echo                                `` :mdmdmdmmddddddddddddddddddddddy`                                
echo                                 ` oNmmmmddddddddddddddddddddddmmmd.   `                            
echo                                 ` yNmNNNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm:                                
echo                                ` .dNmNmNNmmNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmN+ ``                             
echo                                ` :NmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmNy `   ``                         
echo                               `  oNmmmmNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm.    `                          
echo                                ` hNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmN: `      `                      
echo                 ``            ` .mNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmN+ `` ``   `                     
echo              `    `    `..-/++osyNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmNmNy```   ``                       
echo             ` `   `.:+syhddddddmmmNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmNmyoo/:-.``                      
echo            ` ``-/shhddddddddddddmNNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmNmdddddddhyo+:-```  ```          
echo          ` `.+ydddddddddddddddddNNNNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmdddmddddmmddhyo:.``           
echo          ``+dddddddddddddddddmmmNNNNmmmmmmmmdddddmddddddddmmdmmmmmmNmdmdddddddddddddddy/`          
echo       `  `ydddddddddddddddddddmNNNNNmmmmmdddddddddddddddddddddmmmNNNmdddddddddddddddddddd/``       
echo          omdmdddddddddddddddddmNNNmmmmmmmmddddddddddddddddddddmmNNNmmdmddddddddddddddddddd. `      
echo        ` omddddddddddddmddddmmdmmmmmmNmmmmmddddddddddddddddmmmmmNmmmdddddddddddddddddddddy` ` `    
echo          `ymdddddddddddddddddmddddmmmmmmmmmdddddddddddddddddmmmdmddddddddddddddddddddddds. ``      
echo        `  `+dmdddddmmdmmmmddmmmdddddmmmddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddmmddmddddddmh+.`  ` `     
echo         `` ``/shmdmddmmmmmmmddddmmmmmmmmmmdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddmmddmdddddhy+-` `  ` `      
echo        `   ` ```-/oyhdddmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmdddddddddddddmddddmmmdmmddddddddddhyo/-`   ` ` `   `     
echo         ` ` ` `  `  ``-/+sydddddddddmddmmdmdddmdddddmmmdmmmdddddddhhhhhho/-.`  `                   
echo                     ``` ` :mNMNNNNNmdhhhhhhhddddddddhdhhhhhhhyyhmmNNNmmd. `                        
echo                        ` :mNNNNNMNNNhsooo+++++oyyo+oo++/://++++sNNNNNNmh/ ``                       
echo                     ``` :dNNNNNNMNNNdyssoo++/+oyy++o++////+oooohNNNNNNmd/ ` ` `                    
echo                       `:dNNNNNNMNNNNmyyssooo+osyy++ooo++++oosssdNNNNNNmdo `  `                     
echo                    ``./hNNNNNNNNNNNmNdsyhhoooyoys+/+o+++++yhssymNNNNNNmdy.                         
echo                ` `` .oymNNNNmNNNMNNNNMhosdmdysohho+hs+++sddossmNNNNNNNmdmo````                     
echo                 ` ` -/smNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNdosyydmmmdoodNmmddssosmMNmNNNNNmmdds:.`                     
echo `               ` ` .+dmNNNmNNNNNNNNNNMNdosyssssoo+osoooososmMMNmNNNNmNmmddds:.``                  
echo   ` ``` ``  ` ``.-/odNNNNNNmNMNNNNNNMMMMMmssyooooyys++++oohNMMMNmNNNNmNmmmmNNNmdho-`   `           
echo `   `` `.-/+syhdmNNNNMMNNNNNNNNNNNNmNMNNMNNhso++smms//+oodNNMMNmNmmNNmNNmNmNNNNNNNmhs/.`    ` `    
echo `  `  .+ydmNNNNNNNNNMNMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMMMNMMNmy+/hmdh:++yNNNMMMNNNmmmmmNNmNNNNNNNNNNNNmmhs:.` `     
echo  ```/dmNNNNNNNMNNNMMMMMMNMNNNNNNNNmNNMMMMMNMNNh+omNo/sdMNMNNMMNNNmmmmmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmNmds:``   `
echo ``.smmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNMNNNMNNmNmNNMNMMMNNNNNNdNmdmNNNNNNMMNNNNNNmmmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmh/`  `
echo ``/dmmNmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMMNNNNmmNNNMMMMMMMMMMMNMNNMNMNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmNmmmms. `
echo NmmmmNNNmmmmNNNNNNNNNNNMMMNNNNNmNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNNMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmNmmmmmh-`
echo mmmmNmNmmmmmmmNNNNNNNNMMMMMMMMNNNmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNNNmmmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmmmmmmmd:
echo mNNmmmmmmmmmmNNNNNMMMMMMNMNMMMMNNmNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
echo NmmmmmmmmmmmNNNNNNNNMMNNNMNNNMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNmmmmmmmmmmmmm
echo(
echo                    "/  |  /  |                    /  |                          ";
echo                    "$$ |  $$ |  ______    _______ $$ |   __   ______    ______  ";
echo                    "$$ |__$$ | /      \  /       |$$ |  /  | /      \  /      \ ";
echo                    "$$    $$ | $$$$$$  |/$$$$$$$/ $$ |_/$$/ /$$$$$$  |/$$$$$$  |";
echo                    "$$$$$$$$ | /    $$ |$$ |      $$   $$<  $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |";
echo                    "$$ |  $$ |/$$$$$$$ |$$ \_____ $$$$$$  \ $$ \__$$ |$$ \__$$ |";
echo                    "$$ |  $$ |$$    $$ |$$       |$$ | $$  |$$    $$/ $$    $$/ ";
echo                    "$$/   $$/  $$$$$$$/  $$$$$$$/ $$/   $$/  $$$$$$/   $$$$$$/  ";
echo                    "                                                            ";
echo                    "                                                            ";

Set vbsfile=%temp%\Intro.vbs
Set URL=http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
Timeout /T 18 /Nobreak>nul
::********************************************************************
Set MyFile=%~f0
Set ShorcutName=Block-UnBlock_Facebook
(
echo Call Shortcut("%MyFile%","%ShorcutName%"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Start /Wait %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Del %temp%\Shortcutme.vbs
Goto:CheckPassword
::****************************************************************************************************
:EOF
EXIT
``````````

Comment: Awesome :-O, I have one more issue while blocking in the data already in host file is overwriting, I need it all the time,
Thanks @Hackoo for this Awesome code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block facebook via hosts forwarding it to localhost.

Do it on your router or firewall.

But if works for you Go with batch file.
Block

best use this vbs

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26971010/VBScript-Hosts-File-add-remove-multiple-entries.html

Comment: You absolutely can, should is another question... Also, Experts Exchange is a terrible place to link to (paywall!!!)

Comment: BDW the vbs script works good, you can test on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is our solution then.

Unblock

```
$HostFile = "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"

$Hosts = Get-Content -Path $HostFile 
(Get-Content $HostFile) -replace '127.0.0.1 Facebook.com', '#127.0.0.1 Facebook.com' | Set-Content $HostFile
```

Block

```
$HostFile = "$($env:windir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$Hosts = Get-Content -Path $HostFile 
(Get-Content $HostFile) -replace '#127.0.0.1 Facebook.com', '127.0.0.1 Facebook.com' | Set-Content $HostFile
```