# Editing hosts with batch file windows 10

Tags: batch-file

Hello i've been looking for a batch file that is able to edit my hosts file in windows 10 but apparently none is working. I've been trying to use these two codes combined found in this forum.

```
REM --add the following to the top of your bat file--


@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params = %*:"=""
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"

SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

FIND /C /I "ns1.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^62.116.159.4 ns1.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns2.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^217.160.113.37 ns2.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns3.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^89.146.248.4  ns3.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns4.intranet.de" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^74.208.254.4 ns4.intranet.de>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

What i get when i try to run is that windows defender blocked the file because of the security reasons. How to make it work?

It's painful to change hosts file manually two days a week in normal way.

Comment: This question is about security and not about code. It should be on Superuser.

Comment: actually no it's not. The script seems to not be working even if i turn off Smart Screen filter. Asks me 3 times for permisions and at the end when it says it's been done nothing is added to the hosts file.

Comment: Try disabling windows defender and exclude the file you are trying to run. Run as admin and lower your UAC settings in control panel.

Comment: Check if the hosts file is read only or not ; if yes; you should add this line **attrib -r pathtohosts**

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221819/how-to-block-social-medias-from-windows

Answer (score 0):

Download the hostsfileeditor it makes it a snap to change.